# Exception str() failed

Tags: python, string, raspberry-pi, libgphoto2

I'm starting to create a new 3D scanner with a Raspberry Pi 3B + and a Canon 6D. I have a part of the Python code to recover the images thanks to the gphoto2 library but I can't put my ISO configuration on the reflex.

I have already done several tests but nothing works. I always have the same error:

I use the gp command to send all parameters to the Canon reflex.

Import :

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from sh import gphoto2 as gp
import signal, os, subprocess, shutil
```

Gp command example (all works) :

```
CaptureImageDownload = ["--capture-image-and-download"]
CaptureImage = ["--capture-image"]
```

But this line don't work :

```
ValueISO = ["--set-config iso=0"]
```

Here is the error displayed in the command terminal

```
File "CameraShot.py", line 124, in <module>
gp(ValueISO)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1427, in __call__
return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 774, in __init__
self.wait()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: <exception str() failed>
```

I can not write this command line otherwise my camera does not understand the order.

Comment: What exactly is `sh.py`? What project is that, isn't that a [subprocess replacement](https://github.com/amoffat/sh)? Why not use a [real `gphoto2` library](https://pypi.org/project/gphoto2/)

Comment: The error you see is generated by the `gphoto2 --set-config iso=0` command executed via `sh`. You'll have to read the documentation for that command-line tool, this really isn't a Python issue here.

Comment: The `<exception str() failed>` line means that `str(exception)` failed when Python tried to render that exception. I see that the `sh` project mixes in Unicode data into the exception message, so there is probably a non-ASCII character in the stdout or stderr error output that `gphoto2 --set-config iso=0` generated when it exited with status code 1.

Comment: Hi, actually I took over one of my classmates and he started the project with the sh method. No problem for all the basic commands we will say but as soon as there is a space in the command it shows me this error.

Comment: Have you considered passing in your arguments as *separate strings*? I haven't looked at the `sh` documentation, but if you pass in arguments as a list, then I am reasonably certain that `sh` wants you to pass in the arguments pre-parsed: `ValueISO = ["--set-config", "iso=0"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`sh` documentation on passing in arguments](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/passing_arguments.html#passing-arguments):

> When passing multiple arguments to a command, each argument *must* be a separate string[.]

Yours are not separate strings. Split out the different parts (on spaces not surrounded by quotes):

```
ValueISO = ["--set-config", "iso=0"]
```

Also see the project's [detailed explanation on why this is](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/faq.html#faq-separate-args); but the short answer is that `sh` is not parsing arguments into separate strings like a shell would.

You can also use the [`shlex.split()` function](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to handle the splitting for you:

```
ValueISO = shlex.split("--set-config iso=0")
```

Note that `sh` also [supports using keyword arguments](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/passing_arguments.html#keyword-arguments), where `set_config="iso=0"` is translated to `["--set-config", "iso=0"]` for you. You could use that as:

```
value_iso = dict(set_config="iso=0")
```

then

```
gp(**value_iso)
```

That you get `sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: <exception str() failed>` is probably a bug in `sh`. Python uses `type(exception).__name__: str(exception)` as the last line of a traceback, and the `str()` call fails on the `sh.ErrorReturnCode` exception (`sh.ErrorReturnCode_1` is a [subclass of `sh.ErrorReturnCode`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/exit_codes.html)). I can see from the [`sh` source code for the exception class](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/858adf0c682af4c40e41f34d6926696b7a5d3b12/sh.py#L384-L388) that the error message is decoded from bytes to Unicode text, and Python 2 can't actually handle Unicode objects returned from a `__str__` method. I've [filed a bug report with `sh`](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/issues/463) to have that fixed.

Comment: Thank you now it works perfectly with the shlex method.